# How to find element in Selenium web driver if xpath and class name is same

Tags: css, xpath

I am trying to find an element using junit in the below HTML code:

```
<div id="leftNav_updateProfile" class="leftNavBullet">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://my.naukri.com/Profile/edit?id=&altresid=">
                <span class="gryTxt">• </span>
                Snapshot
            </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I am confused as i am new to selenium , how to find element here in this code.
Let me try to explain the actual scenario, what i am trying to achieve. On GUI there is a Button "Snapshot" for which the code is above. I tried to find element for this button using xpath :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='leftNav_updateProfile']/ul/li/a[1]")).click();
```

But its not working. Please help me how to find element in situation like these.
It's not important that i am only looking to achieve it through Xpath , any method would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I find the `CssSelector` being easier to use. Your case:

```
driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("#leftNav_updateProfile ul li a")).click();
```

---

If you are new to css selectors here are a few pointers:

Tags are written as they are (see `ul` in example)

`#` precedes an *id* (see `leftNav_updateProfile` in example)

`.` precedes a *class name* (if we were targeting the `span` in your example we would write `.gryTxt`)

To imply a descendant - put a space (in example `ul li a` means: `a` which is a descendant of `li` which is a descendant of `ul`)

To learn further [try this](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-WF0CF/0/1)

Comment: Hi, 
this is extremely useful , i am targetting snapshot in the above code , could you please explain how can i achieve that ?

Comment: Did you try the code in my answer? I think it should work

Comment: Yes, I tried it did not work. Please note i am  trying to target inner text which is "Snapshot" and due to some reason its not hitting that target.

Comment: Can you post your full html page?

Comment: I am sorry i am unable to do it as its a very long html code.

Comment: Are you sure selenium is failing because the element is not found?

Comment: Yes i have pasted from eclipse itself

Comment: Where are you getting an error message and what does it say?

Comment: Can you see the page loading in the browser?

Comment: Yes, absolutely i am able to load the page in the browser

Comment: please note it is a text "Snapshot" under Span Class , so may be we need to get this text to click on this button , i am not sure i am new just guessing.

Comment: Clicking is done on elements, not on text. Targeting the `a` element is correct. Might you have 2 `div` elements with the same id?

Comment: I am able to do it now using code suggested by you above , only difference is instead of space i used ">" in case of desendants.

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#leftNav_updateProfile > ul > li > a")).click();

Comment: Interesting, since space is more general than `>`. Glad it works, anyhow